# Healthy recipe for Quaker oatmeal packets?

Tags: cookies

I have a bunch of these *maple & brown sugar Quaker oatmeal packets* and I'm looking for a healthy (and simple) *chewy cookie* recipe that I can use them with.

I've searched, but I only see recipes that use unhealthy ingredients (butter, chocolate chips, etc). I've also found recipes that are very complicated.

So I guess my question is: how can I make chewy cookies with just these oatmeal packets? Since I'm not much of a cook, I prefer something that isn't overly complicated and doesn't require many additional ingredients (ie. I can use what I have in my kitchen).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this question is off-topic (https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), but I'll respond on the basis that anyone looking for a non-fattening cookie recipe has probably suffered sufficiently already.

Looking on the Quaker site, they have a decent recipe albeit with butter (https://www.quakeroats.com/cooking-and-recipes/vanishing-oatmeal-raisin-cookies). Taking into account the dryness of the oats, you could try amending this and reducing the butter content and replacing that with some egg white until the consistency is close to a traditional recipe.

Another alternative is banana, see https://cafedelites.com/healthy-2-ingredient-breakfast-cookies which is just oats and banana.

Either way, you will probably be able to put something together that resembles a cookie, but for that really luxurious cookie experience, butter, sugar and chocolate are hard to beat.

Comment: Well, you can easily make something like flapjack with oats… but not with instant oats; they're almost a powder, no body to them at all. They'd come out with the consistency of a floor tile.

Comment: plus, those instant packets have sugar and flavourings already added. Trying to make a cookie with them is not like trying to make one with just plain oatmeal. Someone who feels butter and chocolate are unhealthy should avoid the packets: they have far more sugar than chocolate does.